# How do I stop a NumericUpDown from playing 'Ding' sound on EnterKeyPress

Tags: c#, alert, numericupdown

I have a few `NumericUpDown` controls on my form, and everytime I hit the enter key while it is active, it plays this horrible DING noise, right in my ears. It plays if I don't handle the `KeyPress` event, and it plays if I do handle the `KeyPress` event, with or without `e.Handled = true`:

```
myNumericUpDown.KeyPress += myNumericUpDown_KeyPress;
```

```
private void myNumericUpDown_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        e.Handled = true; //adding / removing this has no effect
        myButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

And I don't think it is happening because I am handling it, as if I don't register the event (removing the first line above), it still plays the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use KeyDown() and SuppressKeyPress, but click the button in KeyUp():

```
    private void myNumericUpDown_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }

    private void myNumericUpDown_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            myButton.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

*If you set the Forms `AcceptButton` Property to "myButton", then **NO** code is needed at all!

Comment: It doesn't work when `myButton` creates a MessageBox.

Comment: The code did not work for me (my project is in vb.net but this is very simple code to convert), but setting `AcceptButton` on the form did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

NumericUpDown also checks if the key you pressed is a "number key" (1-9,-,.), which is obviously not the case for the enter key. After you did what you wanted to do, just set `e.KeyChar` to any number key. Setting `e.Handled = true` is still necessary, otherwise the system treats your input as if you actually pressed that key instead and inserts the number.

```
//Do something
e.Handled = true;
e.KeyChar = (char)Keys.D2;
```

For me, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are not supposed to use the Enter key like that in a GUI app.  It is reserved for another role.  The DING! is an unsubtle reminder of that.

You can easily unding it by actually giving the Enter key the intended usage.  Drop a button on the form, set its Visible property to False.  Select the form and set the AcceptButton property to that button.  No more dings.

Extrapolating somewhat from the odd usage of Enter, you probably want to make the Enter key behave like it does in a console mode app, taking the user to the next control.  Normally done by using the Tab key instead.  You can accomplish that, and unding you UI, by copy/pasting this code into your form class:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter) {
            var ctl = this.ActiveControl;
            var box = ctl as TextBoxBase;
            // Make Enter behave like Tab, unless it is a multiline textbox
            if (ctl != null && (box == null || !box.Multiline)) {
                this.SelectNextControl(ctl, true, true, true, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the AcceptButton property of the form doens't work when another control has focus, such as a NumericUpDown, which is why I am trying to remove the ding when I hit enter from the NumericUpDown

Comment: Hmm, no, that works fine.  Anyhoo, you got two solutions, pick the one you like.

Comment: Also I did test the AcceptButton thing, and it doens't work with NumericUpDown in WinForms, at least for me.

Comment: What is the role the Enter button is reserved to? In my application I need to constrain when the user finishes editing the NumericUpDown. So that while the value is being edited it doesn't affect the expensive instrument the UI controls with nonsensical values. The Enter is the perfect key to assert the value.

Comment: Operate the AcceptButton.  In your case you'd consider a button labeled "Apply", whose Click event handler updates the instrument.

Answer (score 1):

I do this trick:

Inside the `numericUpandDown` KeyPress function, if `e.KeyChar=13` (Enter key), you have to set `e.Handled=true;` (that will prevent your control from changing it's value in any way) and just after that `set e.KeyChar=(char)46;` (or any other numerical accepted value, it will not be written as `e.Handled` is already set to true).

This way, `e.KeyChar` has an accepted value by Visual Studio, and that "Ding" will not sound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with any of these Key event solutions that prevent the NumericUpDown from seeing the ENTER key is that ENTER has the desirable action of causing the ValueChanged event. Important when the user types in the control and hits ENTER to commit the value.

My solution is to put a dummy button on the form and set it as the 'AcceptButton' to silence the DING. It has to be Visible and Enabled. And we need to set TabStop to false and hide it below another control so the user cannot interact with it directly. Fortunately the button doesn't steal focus and we can use that to test which control on the form the ENTER key belongs to in the button's Click event, where the NumericUpDown also, fortunately, reports it's value as the typed text.

```
    private void buttonDummy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDownCtrl.Focused)
            numericUpDownCtrl_ValueChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```